# Would the earth being absent screw up the orbit of the other planets?

Tags: dc, stargate

In a final season episode of Stargate, they make the earth intangible/phase out to protect from an attack from the Ori. In the movie Justice League: Doom they do the same thing, except to protect from a solar flare.

Would making the earth intangible not screw with the other planets, or the gravity of the earth for that matter?

Comment: Define your tolerance for "screw up". Nothing is going to go flying out of the solar system, but orbits will be perturbed.

Comment: Wouldn't this be better suited for [physics.se] or [astronomy.se]?

Comment: @Iszi [astronomy.se] is no more (see [When a site grows quiet](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/04/when-a-site-grows-quiet/). [physics.se] would want a definition of *intangible*. Given that this intangibility is only defined in fictional universes, the question is on-topic here and off-topic on [physics.se].

Comment: @Gilles - Perhaps it (definition) can be solidified to "What would be the effect of **completely removing** Earth from the N-body Solar system"? I presume that from gravitational standpoint, "phasing out" amounts to complete removal from the set of forces. I have a sneaky suscpicion that some physicist/astronomer have already run that model - it's too juicy of a fun problem NOT to have been looked at.

Comment: @DVK Sure. That would be a different question. From past interactions with [physics.se] mods about similar topics, I gather they would reject this question because making Earth intangible is not necessarily the same as removing Earth.

Comment: @Gilles - Didn't see the end of SG1, so I'll trust you on that. Physics is picky, I agree, but they took a couple of my SFF inspired questions before - I might try on this one if I have time

Comment: If you ask on Physics I'll give the same answer there, with more math :) We don't mind this kind of question as long as it is clearly-worded and deals with real-world science.

Comment: This question is totally off-topic.   Either it's about real-world physics, or, if it's about the effect in-universe, then the question needs to be limited to a single universe.    VTC.

Comment: Off-topic; send it to http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it would affect the orbits. The Earth is in an [orbital resonance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_resonance) with Venus - actually there are two resonances, with periods of 1,000 years and 50,000 years. The 50,000-year resonance is fairly strong - this means over time the absence of Earth would begin to perturb Venus' orbit.

Earth is also in a minor resonace with Mars and Jupiter but probably this wouldn't affect their orbits significantly.

The moon would have a bigger issue. No Earth means that the Moon would settle into and take over the Earth's orbit.

NOTE: These would take a long time to take effect, over millions of years. So a brief period of intangibility would not affect the other planets. The Moon would still be screwed. Removing Earth's gravity would make it immediately start to drift.

NOTE 2: This assumes that "intangibility" and "phasing" are equivalent to instantaneously removing Earth from the system. Since "intangibility" and "phasing" aren't defined rigorously (if at all) it may be the best we can do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess one solution would be if they made the moon intangible as well, although that wasn't mentioned I guess it could be implied.